# UIPickerView default row

Tags: ios, swift2, uipickerview

If I want to have the default row when the view controller starts as [2] or any other row number, how do I carry that out?

```
var pickerData = ["2x2","4x4","6x6","8x8","12x12"]    


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    totalTilesLabel.text = pickerData[8]

    
    display.text = sentData
    self.picker.delegate = self
    self.picker.dataSource = self

}
```

This is the UIPicker datasource and delegate.

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the picker view's selected row to whatever initial row you want in the `viewDidLoad` method. Here's Swift 3 code. Adjust as needed for Swift 2.

```
self.picker.selectRow(8, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
```

Comment: Yes It worked in Swift 2. Just one note, the line of code has to be after the self.picker.delegate = self
self.picker.dataSource = self

Comment: Yes, if you attempt to select the row before setting the data source it won't work because there won't be any data in the picker view. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your issue.